# how can i make an javascript object for a HTML form

Tags: javascript, oop

i want to make an object which can do all the actions my form needs -- it can validate the form, submit the form, and so forth. i want javascript to do all these things. i no longer want to write same code several times over in procedural fashion javascript in global namespace. i want to create Javascript object to handle these functions of the form and i want to have everything live in a namespace to avoid conflicts.

i have hard time to understand how javascript OO works compared to other language with classical inheritance vs prototype inheritance. can somebody show me how to create a class, and then instantiate 2 objects of that class and bind each of them to two identical form on the same page?

i look at module pattern but it seems for singleton only.

thanks if anybody can help

Comment: Maybe this already helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 3):

Don't reinvent the wheel. If you want to perform form validation and submit based on validation you can try using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and [jQuery validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

To understand Javascript's prototype-based OO model, there are many resources:

1. [Javascript: The world's most misunderstood programming language](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/javascript.html) (start here - it's by Douglas Crockford)
2. [Introduction to Object Oriented Programming in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) (from the Mozilla Developer Center)

Comment: thank you for the links, the mozilla one looks better than most tutorials i see so far.  unfortunately most show only simple examples but i dont see how to go from global namespace to namespaced classes. i will continue reading the sources u provide before coming back with more questions -- maybe it will become clear

Comment: You can have a form of namespacing through the module pattern. Of course, this means that you have only a singleton. In most cases that should be what you need. Otherwise you can resort to using object literals. Another way of namespacing is to have `var my = {}; var my.namespace = {}; var my.namespace.myFunc = function() { ... };` IMO the module pattern is better because it provides encapsulation. Be careful though. Namespacing and making objects are two different things.